# get response code from url without other data like (html or xml or json)

Tags: java, android

i am doing android application it need a server url call which need only response code for identify the call has successfully made ( like 200 ) but no need of any other data like json.

in other words i dont want to implement the reader objects (inputStreamReader) and bla bla bla..

so the code will be like 
       call url 
       get response code 
       exit

Comment: what is your plane to do this ?

Comment: That's not how the infrastructure works. You don't just get an int response it is wrapped up with a lot of other information that you will need to catch and can then ignore.

Comment: hi @sky can you look my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(myUri);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(); // Your status-code
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the HTTP HEAD request, for example using [apache http client](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpHead.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use status code:

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);
int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
URL obj = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
// you can set the required parameter for your connection object
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this please on your post execute method from asyntask method:

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
    // Set up HTTP post 
    // HttpClient is more then less deprecated. Need to change to URLConnection 
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient( ); 
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(params[0]); 
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
   if (statusCode == 200) { 
   //do some work
   }
```